# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied - Windows 10 Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am currently learning python, coming from java, and stumbled into an error I can't find the answer to. I am using the latest python version on Windows 10, though I assume the tutorial I followed was meant for Linux... Hope you can still help me out. This is my classcode:

```
def main():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 
    socket.IPPROTO_IP)

    #mainloop
    raw_data, addr = connection.recvfrom(65536)
    dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)
    print('\nEthernet Frame:')
    print('Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(dest_mac, 
    src_mac, eth_proto))

#unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])

    return get_mac_addr(dest_mac), get_mac_addr(src_mac), 
    socket.htons(proto), data[14:]

#format MAC adress
def get_mac_addr(bytes_addr):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)

    return ':'.join(bytes_str).upper()

main()
```

On execution I receive following Error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

in the line with "connection.recvfrom(65536)".

Is this a windows specific error?

Comment: Do you want a TCP or UDP socket? `recvfrom` is generally for UDP but you're making a TCP.

Comment: To be honest, I dont know... this is from a sniffer tutorial, what makes most sense? And what solution would be best for which? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: I would read up on it, but TCP is slower and more reliable whereas UDP is faster and less reliable. TCP is also accessed more like a file whereas UDP is packet based.

Comment: I see, yeah have some very basic knowledge about TCP and UDP, but considering I wanna go for TCP, how can I fix my current issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The socket does not have an address until it is either bound or data is sent. Bind the socket before calling `connection.recvfrom(65536)` using `connection.bind((YOUR_IP, PORT))`.

Comment: Note that at that point you don't need to do `recvfrom` as `recv` will work just as well since you know the IP and port.

Comment: Is there a way to find the port number dynamically from client-side?