# how do i make my server able to read data which is sent by client

Tags: python-3.x

here i am making server

```
my_selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()
keep_running = True

server_address = ('localhost', 1040)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(False)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(5)
my_selector.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)
```

this accept function make new connection

```
def accept(sock):
    # print("Accept Function")
    new_connection, addr = sock.accept()
    print("Connection established.......")
    new_connection.setblocking(False)
    my_selector.register(new_connection, selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE, data=None)
```

this read function reads data sent by client

```
def read(connection, mask):
    global keep_running
    print("Read Function")
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = connection.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            print("Message received ", recv_data.decode("utf-8"))
        else:
            print("Message not received")
            my_selector.unregister(connection)
            connection.close()
            keep_running = False
```

this loop controls my server

```
while keep_running:
    for key, mask in my_selector.select(timeout=None):
        if key.data is None:
            accept(key.fileobj)
        else:
            read(key, mask)

my_selector.close()
```

my question is when server and client run if server gets a new client it control goes to accept function
or if server gets data it goes to read function this programme shows error
client programme does not show any error client programme only send data
please tell me how to fix this error and i am working on windows 10

```
Error----OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post maybe it helps you :)
The first answer on that where the guy is having the same error says:

Bind the socket before calling `connection.recvfrom(65536)` using `connection.bind((YOUR_IP, PORT))`.

[OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied - Windows 10 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330897/oserror-winerror-10022-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-windows-10-python)