# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied in socket.listen(2)

Tags: python, invalid-argument

I am running this server code on Visual Studio Code for a server project:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import sys

server = "192.168.0.4"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))

except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)

print("Waiting for connections...")
print("Server Started!")

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            reply = data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                print("Disconnected!")
                break

            else:
                print("Received: ", reply)
                print("Sending: ", reply)

            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))

        except:
            break

        print("Lost Connection!")
        conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

And for some reason I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sande/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/VisualStudiosCode/RPSOnline/server.py", line 16, in <module>
    s.listen(2)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Pls help me in why this is happening. I tried re - writing the code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you think `str(e)` is going to do in the exception handler, you may want to `print(e)` instead. If the bind fails, the listen will also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330897/oserror-winerror-10022-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-windows-10-python

Comment: Thanks. Figured out the error. Thanks to paxdiablo for helping me out!!